# NSPredicate for 2-level drill-down?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

A core data entity A has a to-many relationship to entity B, which has a to-many relationship with entity C, which has two attributes:type and value.

A =>> B =>> C 
(So: A.Bs.Cs.type, A.Bs.Cs.value)

Whats an `NSArray` filter predicate for all A's that have any B that has any C that has (type=='test1' && value=='test2')?

The subquery samples I've seen only go 1 level deep.

I also tried `[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:]` 
with subpredicate 1) "ANY Bs.Cs.type=='test1'" and subpredicate 2) "ANY Bs.Cs.value=='test2'", but nothing is returned.

Yes, I've looked at the `NSPredicate` & friends docs, but can't find anything about multi-level drilldowns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [NSExpression +expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForSubquery%3ausingIteratorVariable%3apredicate%3a) or the expression syntax documented there.

I think for your case it would be something like

```
(SUBQUERY(Bs, $b, 
   SUBQUERY($b.Cs, $c, $c.type=='text1' && $c.value='test2').@count != 0
 ).@count != 0)
```

Comment: Yep, works perfectly. Thank you so much. This would have taken me a long time to figure out.