# NSPredicate for one-to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

- Assuming a **Department** entity and an **Employee** entity with a one-many relationship
- Assuming relationship called **employees** on Department and **department** on Employee
- Assuming Employee has an attribute **name**

I need to fetch all Departments that don't have an Employee called "Bob"

Based on other answers on SO that I've read, I've tried this:

```
name = @"Bob";
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ALL employees.name != %@", name];
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5041663/166955

Comment: No, here is the exact duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347776/how-to-correctly-setup-a-nspredicate-for-a-to-many-relationship-when-using-core

Comment: Thanks. For the record I needed to change it to: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@(SUBQUERY(employees, $sub, $sub.name == %@).@count == 0)`, name];

Comment: @dnickthomas: A SUBQUERY is not really needed here, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do do not need a subquery here:

```
name = @"Bob";
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT ANY employees.name == %@", name];
```

For some reason, the "ALL" aggregate does not work with to-many relationships, but the "ANY" aggregate works.